# Adding another tableview

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios5, storyboard, drilldown

Hi been following this tutorial http://codingandcoffee.wordpress.com/2011/10/12/iphone-tutorial-two-combining-uitabbarcontrollers-uitableviews-and-uinavigationcontrollers/ and managed to complete it successfully however would someone be able to help me add in another tableview before the detail view, and therefore drilling down e.g. object 1 ---> object 1a --->detail view.

Thanks

**EDIT**
Okay so the data structure I'm looking at is like this:

```
object1 --> object 1a--> detail 1a (all the detail view will just contain an image)
        --> object 1b--> detail 1b
        --> object 1c--> detail 1c
        --> object 1d--> detail 1d
        --> object 1e--> detail 1e
object2 --> object 2a--> detail 2a
        --> object 2b--> detail 2b
        --> object 2c--> detail 2c
        --> object 2d--> detail 2d
        --> object 2e--> detail 2e
```

And so on..
So i can implement object 1 into detail 1a using this tutorial however i need to implement the tableview in the middle.
I hope this has made it clearer.

Comment: Try to rephrase your question because is very generic. Maybe you could explain what structure you have and what you would like to have.

Comment: Hopefully i have made it clearer!

Answer (score 0):

So, do you want to have a **UINavigationController** -> **UINavigationController** - > **Detail View**, right? First of all, your first view need to be a UINavigationController, like this:

```
FirstView : UINavigationController
```

After, you need to add a New File: an **UIViewController** subclass of **UITableViewController** and name it as **SecondTableView** (Or something that you want). So, in the UINavigationController, you need to add in the top of the .m file:

> impot "SecondTableView.h"

And in the:

> - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

You need to put this:

```
SecondTableView *viewC = [[SecondTableView alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondTableView" bundle:nil];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:viewC animated:YES];

[viewC release];
```

Hope that is going to help you, and sorry for the bad english,

Alberto

Comment: It's not a good idea to subclass *UINavigationController*. In addition it's not necessary to add another *UINavigationController*. Maybe you could modify your anser..

Comment: Sure not, but in a new in objective-c case, this is the easiest way.

Comment: Okay i think i understand this so in the second table view controller would i implement an if statement e.g if object 1 selected then display object 1a, object 1b, object 1c in table